# Qt: Does a reimplemented paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) do hidden background work?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently chewing through C++ GUI Programming with Qt4 (Blanchette/Summerfield). In the 5. chapter a basic widget to plot a data set is presented, including a zoom function and view selection via a rubberband that is painted manually (not using QRubberBand).

To manually paint the rubberband, the widget reimplements the handler for paint events:

```
void Plotter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap); //This widget is always drawn from a pixmap

    if (rubberBandIsShown) {
        painter.setPen(palette().light().color());
        painter.drawRect(rubberBandRect.normalized()
                                       .adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));
    }

 ...
}
```

Notice that the handler does not make use of any argument, which looks to me as if it always painted the whole widget (the pixmap + the rubberband if necessary). However, in another function the author calls `update(QRect)` multiple times, specifying an area to be updated:

```
void Plotter::updateRubberBandRegion()
{
    QRect rect = rubberBandRect.normalized();
    update(rect.left(), rect.top(), rect.width(), 1);
    update(rect.left(), rect.top(), 1, rect.height());
    update(rect.left(), rect.bottom(), rect.width(), 1);
    update(rect.right(), rect.top(), 1, rect.height());
}
```

Now my questions is: Why are the above updates scheduled for a specific rectangle of the widget while the paint event dicards any positional information and paints the whole widget instead? Couldn't I just have called `update()` once without arguments?

No part in the implementation of the paint event handler makes use of any rectangle or area (no `event->rect()` or alike), unless I misunderstood something horribly or `paintEvent(..)` is smarter than its implementation and additional background work is done that I am not aware of.

Thanks a lot.

I'm using Qt 4.8.6 with g++ 4.8.2 on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Several sequential calls of `update` will generate only 1 paint event. It's well documented. Forced repainting may be done with `repaint` method. And Qt implements double-buffering inside it's drawing engine.

Comment: @SaZ You're right, I forgot that updates are managed intelligently by Qt, saving paint events where possible. I adapted my question slightly.

Comment: In your case, complete repainting will be done.